# Analytical solution for a variable inside of a summation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation

I am trying to figure out how to solve the following expression for $x$ and I'm surprised that I don't know what to do.

> $$\frac{2n}{x} = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{x-y_{i}}$$

We have that $n$ and $x$ are constants, any ideas?

I've noticed that this expression is equivalent to solving

$$\frac{2n}{x} \prod_{i=1}^{n} (x-y_{i}) = \sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(\prod_{j=1, i\neq j}^{n} (x - y_{j})\right)$$

which looks even harder.

Comment: Unless there is a typo and/or some data is missing (what are the $\,y_i'$s , for example?), I think this is not an easy exercise. In fact, it looks awfully messy and boring, though not that hard. But definitely not trivial at all: $\,x\,$ appears as summand of denominators of a sum...yucks!

Comment: @DonAntonio: $\{y_{1},...,y{n}\}$ is an arbitrary set of non-negative integers with $x \neq y_{i}, \forall i$. It seems really hard to me, any ideas about how it could be not that hard?

Comment: I *really is very hard*, not only messy, even for low positive integral values of $\,n\,$...

Comment: Not only hard: it looks hopeless...are you sure this is the exact identity you need to solve for $\,x\,$ ? Where does it come from?

Comment: By clearing denominators you get a polynomial equation of degree $n$ on the variable $x$. If $n\geq5$, well, you know, life becomes hard...

Comment: Sí...I'd say though that if $\,1<n\le 4\,$ life becomes hard, whereas if $\,n\ge 5\,$ life becomes Abel-Galoisly impossible...

Comment: Fair enough. I asked my professor about it and he said that indeed, this was the equality we had to solve and he knew it was impossible. Then he gave me a completely different way of looking at which the original question (which is far from this equality). Oops. Thanks anyway, guys!